# Why is sequelize not generating automatically my join table?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to make a many to many relationship with sequelize, nodejs, and expressjs.

I have my Sale.model.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

const Sale = sequelize.define('Sale', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    employee_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: 'employees',
            key: 'id'
        },
        required: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    customer_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: 'customers',
            key: 'id'
        },
        required: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    
});

module.exports = Sale;
```

And this is my Service.model.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

const Service = sequelize.define('Service', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true    
    }
});

module.exports = Service;
```

Here is my associations.js where I define the different relationships:

```
const User = require('./User.model');
const Employee = require('./Employee.model');
const Sale = require('./Sale.model');
const Service = require('./Service.model');

Sale.belongsToMany(Service, { through: 'Sale_Services', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
Service.belongsToMany(Sale, { through: 'Sale_Services', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
User.hasOne(Employee, { foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'Employee', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
Employee.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'User', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
```

As the documentation says, when you stablish a many to many relationship a join table is automatically created but for some reason mine is not being generated. I have created my own model Sale_Services and the table was created, but I don´t want to have the model for this table, instead I want to proceed as the sequelize documentation says.

Why is my join table not being created?

This is how I am syncing my tables in server.js

```
sequelize.authenticate()
 .then(() => {
   console.log('Connection to DB successfully stablished.');
 })
 .catch(err => {
   console.error('Erro while trying to connect to DB:', err);
 });

sequelize.sync({ force:false })
 .then(() => console.log('Tables Synced'))
 .catch(error => console.error('Error while syncronizing table:', error));
```

Comment: Did you make sure you have associations registered right before calling `sync`?